# How to adjust gold price based on the consumer index?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I used quandl to get the history price of gold and consumer index. And change the index to yearly data but the gold history price is monthly. I want to adjust the gold price monthly data based on the "consumer price index " yearly data. How can i do it?

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl


start=pd.to_datetime("1970-10-31")
end=pd.datetime.now()

gold= quandl.get("WGC/GOLD_DAILY_USD",start_date=start, end_date=end, authtoken="F51kbhqij4J1o73V5vXT")
index= quandl.get("RATEINF/CPI_USA",start_date=start, end_date=end, authtoken="F51kbhqij4J1o73V5vXT")#RATEINF/CPI_USA

gold.rename(columns={"Value":"Close"},inplace=True)
gold.head()
index.resample("Y").mean()    # get yearly consumer index data to adjust the monthly price of gold
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YVmA.png)

Comment: Please do not share information in images. What is the exact issue here?

Comment: The issue has been described which is how to divide the gold monthly price by the different value of consumer price index in column of " index=index.resample("Y").mean() "

Comment: For those of us who are not familiar with the quandl API, where is the monthly price here? Some more descriptive variable names might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the best path forward is to merge the annual and monthly data and then proceed with your calculations.

(For readability I will refer to your 'index' dataframe as 'consumer' as it can get confusing when accessing each dataframes’ datetime index.)

Starting from:

```
consumer = consumer.resample("y").mean()
```

You first need to pull the year out of the datetime index:

```
gold = gold.reset_index()
consumer = consumer.reset_index()

gold['year'] = gold['Date'].dt.year
consumer['year'] = consumer['Date'].dt.year
```

Then merge the two dataframes on year:

```
gold = gold.merge(consumer,on='year')
```

and return your index back to date time:

```
gold = gold.set_index('Date')
```

This will match the annual consumer index information to the monthly gold pricing information which will allow you to perform whatever adjustments you need.

For example if you want to divide the two:

```
gold['adjusted'] = gold['Close'] / gold['Value']
```